# Add date and time to a file name in c

Tags: c

Im looking for a way to add the current date and time to a log file im opening
for now im using :

```
fopen("/var/log/SA_TEST","w");
```

How to make it

```
fopen("/var/log/SA_TEST_DATE_AND_TIME","w");
```

Thx a lot
(In c)

Comment: Its simple, Use `sprintf`.

Comment: Do you want to rename the file before opening it?

Comment: And in what formta should the date and time be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/* ctime example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, time, ctime */

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  char buffer [255];

  time (&rawtime);
  sprintf(buffer,"/var/log/SA_TEST_%s",ctime(&rawtime) );
// Lets convert space to _ in

char *p = buffer;
for (; *p; ++p)
{
    if (*p == ' ')
          *p = '_';
}



  printf("%s",buffer);
  fopen(buffer,"w");

  return 0;
}
```

**Output is**

```
/var/log/SA_TEST_Wed_Jul_30_12:17:19_2014
```

Comment: what does 
for (; *p; ++p)
mean? is it a normal c loop? i never seen 1 like it

Comment: It will increment pointer to next character and check does it null or not. Yes its a normal loop you can write same in while loop also.

Comment: it hits me with "error creation LOG Gile....: no suck file of directory
maybe i need to add .txt in the end?
but when i try to add .txt it goes to a new line

Comment: This solution looks complicated. I'd go for using `strftime()` as propose by other answers to the question.

Answer (score 11):

`strftime` can be used to format the date an time :

```
#include <time.h>

char filename[40];
struct tm *timenow;

time_t now = time(NULL);
timenow = gmtime(&now);

strftime(filename, sizeof(filename), "/var/log/SA_TEST_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S", timenow);

fopen(filename,"w");
```

You can change the date an time format for whatever you want according to the [strftime manual](http://www.manpages.info/linux/strftime.3.html).

You can use the timestamp as 'compact format' with the result of `time` only.

```
sprintf(filename, "/var/log/SA_TEST_%d", (int)now);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  char buffer [64];

  time (&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

  strftime (buffer,64,"/var/log/SA_TEST_%x_%X",timeinfo);//generate string SA_TEST_DATE_TIME
  fopen(buffer, "w");
```

Refer:
`man strftime`
for the formats you can get time and date in.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sprintf` in following way

```
char date_time[30];   //Collect system date and time in this character array
char filename[40]
sprintf(filename, "/var/log/SA_TEST_%s", date_time);
fopen(filename,"w");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    printf("Runfile: %s Date: %s Time : %s \n", __FILE__, __DATE__, __TIME__ );

    FILE     *fptr;
    char     *fmode, filename[255], strtime_sec[20], strtime_nsec[20];
    struct   tm* tm;            
    struct   timespec ts;
    time_t   now;

    now = time(NULL);          // get current time
    tm  = localtime(&now);     // get time structure

    // Get current time from system clock    
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);

    // Convert integer times to strings using snprintf()
    snprintf(strtime_sec,  20, "%d",  ts.tv_sec);
    snprintf(strtime_nsec, 20, "%ld", ts.tv_nsec);

    // Generate dynamic filename and set filemode
    sprintf(filename, "file_%04d%02d%02d_%s.txt", tm->tm_year+1900, tm->tm_mon+1, tm->tm_mday, strtime_sec);
    fmode = "a";       

    // Open file and write some text into the file
    fptr = fopen(filename, fmode);
    if (fptr == NULL) { 
        printf("Cannot open filename \n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 

    // Test by writing text into the file stream using fprintf()
    fprintf(fptr, "# Runfile: %s Date: %s Time : %s \n", __FILE__, __DATE__, __TIME__ );

    int i; double value, result;
    value = 0.5; 
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       result = value/5.5;
       fprintf(fptr, "%d \t %f \t %f \n", i, value, result);
       value = value * 2.5;
    }
    fclose(fptr);

return(0);
}
```